# Pdfsharp - How to determine the page number of a field

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I need to draw an image on a page that has a specific form field. Using pdfsharp, given a field name, how do I find the pdf page associated with that field?

Answer (score 1):

Here an improvement with corrections which gives also back the pagenum:

```
PdfPage GetPageFromField(PdfDocument myDocument, string focusFieldName, out int pageNum)
{
    // get the field we're looking for
    PdfAcroField currentField = (PdfAcroField)(myDocument.AcroForm.Fields[focusFieldName]);
    pageNum = 0;
    if (currentField != null)
    {
        // get the page element
        var focusPageReference = (PdfReference)currentField.Elements["/P"];
        // loop through our pages to match the reference
        foreach (var page in myDocument.Pages)
        {
            pageNum++;
            if (page.Reference == focusPageReference)
            {
                return page;
            }
        }
    }
    // could not find a page for this field
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the page reference for the field using the page element of the field object. Then use this reference to match the page in the document.

```
public PdfPage GetPageFromField( PdfDocument myDocument, string focusFieldName )
{
  // get the field we're looking for
  PdfTextField currentField = (PdfTextField)( fillablePdf.AcroForm.Fields["MyFocusField"]);
  if( currentField != null )
  {
    // get the page element
    var focusPageReference = (PdfReference)currentField.Elements["/P"];
    // loop through our pages to match the reference
    foreach( var page in myDocument.Pages )
    {
      if( page.Reference = focusPageReference )
      {
        return page;
      }     
    }
  }
  // could not find a page for this field
  return null;
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember the **P** value is not mandatory. Furthermore, what about fields with widgets on multiple pages?